# golang for loop a string, but it prints 'char' as int, why?

Tags: string, go, printing, char, integer

A very simple go function:

```
func genString(v string) {
    for _, c := range v {
        fmt.Println(c)
    }
}
```

Called in:

```
func TestBasics(t *testing.T) {
    genString("abc")
}
```

Then I ran:

```
go test -v -run TestBasics xxxxxx
```

It prints:

```
97
98
99
```

I expected that it should print

```
a
b
c
```

But it prints the corresponding integer value? Why, how to fix it and print just the `char`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why

Looping with `range` over `string` will give you a sequence of `rune`s.

[For `range` spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#For_range):

```
Range expression                          1st value          2nd value

array or slice  a  [n]E, *[n]E, or []E    index    i  int    a[i]       E
string          s  string type            index    i  int    see below  rune
map             m  map[K]V                key      k  K      m[k]       V
channel         c  chan E, <-chan E       element  e  E
```

*(notice the second row and last column in the table)*

> 2. For a string value, the "range" clause **iterates over the Unicode code points** in the string starting at byte index 0. On successive
>    iterations, the index value will be the index of the first byte of
>    successive UTF-8-encoded code points in the string, and **the second
>    value, of type `rune`, will be the value of the corresponding code
>    point**. If the iteration encounters an invalid UTF-8 sequence, the
>    second value will be 0xFFFD, the Unicode replacement character, and
>    the next iteration will advance a single byte in the string.

A [`rune`](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Rune_literals) value is an *integer* value identifying a **Unicode code point**.
The type itself is just an alias of [`int32`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin@go1.19#rune).

---

> how to fix it and print just the char

Use `fmt.Printf` with the `%c` verb to print the character value, i.e. `fmt.Printf("%c\n", c)`

[`fmt` printing verbs doc](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt@go1.19#hdr-Printing):

Integers:

```
%b  base 2
%c  the character represented by the corresponding Unicode code point
%d  base 10
%o  base 8
%O  base 8 with 0o prefix
%q  a single-quoted character literal safely escaped with Go syntax.
%x  base 16, with lower-case letters for a-f
%X  base 16, with upper-case letters for A-F
%U  Unicode format: U+1234; same as "U+%04X"
```

*(notice the second row in the table)*

---

```golang
for _, c := range "abc" {
    fmt.Printf("%c\n", c)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/BEjJof4XvIk